# Delphi shell context-menu, how to draw icon

Tags: delphi, shell, contextmenu

Can I get some code showing how to draw a bitmap/icon on the right-click context menu?

I have working code already for a DLL for the context menu, but it's just text. Example here: http://www.marcocantu.com/code/md5/TODOSHLL.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It [seems](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/445/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) you can simply use the [SetMenuItemBitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Edit: [Here](http://4programmers.net/Icontextmenu_i_Ikon%C4%85)'s a Delphi example.

Edit 2: **Warning**: I just noticed that the Delphi example leaks the bitmap handle and will probably crash the system eventually. The bitmap should be loaded only once in the constructor of the object (and better from its own resource, not from the file system) and released in the destructor.

Comment: Or you can use `InsertMenuItem` instead of `InsertMenu` I guess and do it all in one go.

Comment: Thanks! got it working with SetMenuItemBitmaps (InsertMenuItem seems a lot more complicated). However.. if I free the bitmap after that call, then it doesn't display. Not sure what would be the destructor in the DLL code to free the bitmap :?

Comment: You could override the `constructor`/`destructor` in your `TToDoMenu` class. Or load the bitmap in the `initialization` and release it in the `finalization` section of the unit.

Comment: But there is no finalization in the DLL

Comment: You can [add it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units) in a unit.

Comment: Hmm you are right. Got it all working now, loading from resource etc. Thanks! :)